# OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Tags: metasploit

I am traying to install metasploiteable when execute this comand "vagrant up win2k8" this error appears OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it Modify line 22 of the Vagrantfile file in the repository directory changing win2k8.vm.box = "rapid7/metasploitable3-win2k8" by win2k8.vm.box = "metasploitable3-win2k8". 
https://zrquan.github.io/2018/10/13/Metasploitable3-%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85%E8%AE%B0%E5%BD%95/